# unable to parse json data from local database in flutter 'an error has occurred !'

Tags: json, flutter, api, parsing

```
Future<List<Institute>> fetchInstitute(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.5/tkydatabase/fun/anem.php'));

  // Use the compute function to run parseInstitute in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseInstitute, response.body);
}

List<Institute> parseInstitute(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Institute>((json) => Institute.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Institute>>(
        future: fetchInstitute(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return InstitutesList(institute: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InstitutesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const InstitutesList({super.key, required this.institute});

  final List<Institute> institute;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: institute.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(institute[index].instituteName);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVpAL.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: Can you include about error

Answer (score 0):

- The data from JSON, so it must have a key and value
- is this code help you?

```
    var json =
        '{"body":[{"id":1,"instituteName":"value","instituteWilaya":"value"},{"id":2,"instituteName":"value","instituteWilaya":"value"}]}';
    var map = jsonDecode(json) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    var entityList = map['body'] as List;
    var result = List.generate(
        entityList.length, (index) => Institute.fromJson(entityList[index]));
    print(result);
```